# Need help for search options in Rails2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 2.3.18. Their is a  search need in my application.

I have 3 dynamic select boxes by using JQuery. Select boxes are Country,states,city.

The search options that i need to provide is as follows

1. If three boxes selected for search. Need to fetch data and produce.

2.If any one select box is chossed based on single selection i need to return data. For example , If City alone choosed need to display result set with like country,state,city

I have four tables country,states,cities,Information

i hv hasmany relation frm country to states.

States has hasmany relation with city.

Information table has all fields with countryId,statesId,CityId

I really dont know how to apply search mechanism for this. Can anyine suggest a way

Answer (score 0):

here is the example:

projects/index.rhtml

```
<% form_tag projects_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search1, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

projects_controller.rb

```
def index
  @projects = Project.search1(params[:search1])
end
```

models/project.rb

```
def self.search1(search1)
  if search1
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search1}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank u somuch... I have some times three params, some time two will pass to search, and even one params. How it wuld be

Comment: How are the three search keywords received at index?

Comment: @palani: use search1, search2, search3 etc. I have updated my code.

Comment: I plan to read params using JQuery and plan to use Jquery ajax to submit. In my information table i have only countryId, stateId,Cityid.

Comment: In result set i need to include country,state,city for this info i have separate three tables country,state,city.

Comment: Information is the primary table i am gng to hit. I dont knw hw join the thos three table in search condition.thts my probs